# NetSuite Upload file in Editor from Eclipse IDE

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

'Upload File in Editor' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "Uploading File in Editor".

javax/xml/soap/SOAPException

[I have tried to change the java version in eclipse.ini but it still does not work, any idea?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cccgV.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found recent eclipse releases to be very glitchy.

Spend usd60 and get webstorm... you'll never go back, it is 200% better

Answer (score 0):

You’ll probably need to provide more of the error but if this was previously working you may need to set up a new role. The Full Access role was deprecated in 2020.1 and removed in 2020.2.

Comment: I had similar issues,  even with Administrative

Comment: Admin role and TBA had worked until the last eclipse update

Comment: I have tried also with another role (Developer) and still getting the same error